# Cube.js as reporting tool

Tags: hadoop, hive, analytics, cubes

Can we use cube.js for reporting purpose.
If possible,then how to integrate cube.js with hive database so that I can create my cube on top of my table and trigger query on cube.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can. [Cube.js](https://cube.dev) is designed for this purpose. Hive drivers are in development right now and will be released soon. If you have Presto on top of your Hive you can use it right away. Please check this conversation https://github.com/statsbotco/cube.js/pull/127 and our community [Slack](https://cubejs-community.herokuapp.com/) for updates.

Comment: Can you guide in how to integrate hive with cube.js and any link to follow the instructions.It will be more helpful for me to understand and also to implement.